# Alljoyn onboarding linux Ubuntu x86_64

Tags: java, linux, alljoyn

I'm new to the alljoyn, and I'm trying to run the onboarding services from my ubuntu x86_64.

Is it possible to having an onboarder and an onboardee both in linux x86_64 ?

In the documentation I can't see a clear step by step example where we can perform this (only for Android/IOS as onboarder but not linux) + it says that the actual onboarding samples do not perform the onboarding process as they're using hardcoded configuration.

Could you please help me out ?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to having an onboarder and an onboardee both in linux
>   x86_64 ?

Of course it is possible. You can also use the AllJoyn Dashboard application as an onboarder app which is open source. https://github.com/onbiron/AllJoyn-builds/tree/master/alljoyn

> In the documentation I can't see a clear step by step example where we
>   can perform this (only for Android/IOS as onboarder but not linux) +
>   it says that the actual onboarding samples do not perform the
>   onboarding process as they're using hardcoded configuration.

If you are looking for a reference onboardee implementation, which should onboard the target board, linux, freertos etc. whatever it is on to the supplied Wi-Fi network, I would recommend OnboardingDaemon implementation. https://cgit.allseenalliance.org/services/base.git/tree/onboarding/cpp/src/OnboardingDaemon?h=HEAD